# Snap Friends List

Tags: kinect, xbox-one

What is the voice command to Snap your Friend's List?

I can get the Xbox Live Party to Snap, and find my friends by choosing to Invite More People, but I was looking for a way to keep it in the Snap Bar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can issue a `Xbox Snap Activity` command. From there you can browse to your friends and leave it at that. The list should refresh as your friends change their online state if you sorted it that way.